# How to show the second page as the default page in a jQuery mobile Multi-page template structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I show the second page as the default page in a jQuery mobile Multi-page template structure?

```
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>      
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="bar">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Bar</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>      
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Example

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/UfDaf/

### Code used

This part will prevent normal page load. Don't forget, like in my example mobileinit **MUST** be initialized before **`jQuery Mobile`** is initialized.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit",function() {
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
});
```

This part will start manual page initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    window.location.hash = 'home';
    $.mobile.initializePage();
});
```

While I usually **[advise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)** against of document ready usage here we need it to kick start the manual change.

### Full code example

In case **`jsFiddle`** is down.

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("mobileinit",function() {
                $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
            });        
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="foo">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Foo</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>      
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="bar">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Bar</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>      
            </div>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    window.location.hash = 'home';
    $.mobile.initializePage();
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this if `$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;` is also set?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old but i stumbled on a simple solution:

```
window.location.href = "_dash.html#page-two";
```

or if youre navigating from a seperate page you can make a link that drops u in the second page like so:

```
<a href="_dash.html#page-two">link to second page</a>
```

Simply add the page id for the second page at the end of your url