# jQuery page change not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the page programatically. This first line of code is working, but I don't need it to be delayed, so I tried the second line, but it's not working. What am I missing?

Working (but I don't want the delay):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#pageId', { changeHash: false });
}, 1000);
```

Not working:

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#pageId', { changeHash: false });
```

I'm calling it in the `<head>` of the document, nested in a "web app tester":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && !window.navigator.standalone){
    //is standalone capable, but not in standalone mode
} else if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone){ 
    //is standalone capable, in standalone mode
} else {
    //standalone mode not supported, ie. Desktop.

    //doesnt work:
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#pageId', { changeHash: false });

    //does work, but I don't want the delay:
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#pageId', { changeHash: false });
    }, 1000);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it within $(document).ready() ?

Comment: Is the code snippet executed before your HTML?

Comment: have you called it in document ready, may its due to that the element has not created. Is there any error in console.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've just edited the question to provide further clarification.

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733573/how-to-show-the-second-page-as-the-default-page-in-a-jquery-mobile-multi-page-te) worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It code will works. Please check .

```
$(document).$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#pageId', { changeHash: false });
```

Comment: This didn't work. I tried it as suggested, as well as `$(document).(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#pageId', { changeHash: false });` and `$(document).pagecontainer('change', '#pageId', { changeHash: false });`